# Change php cli version

Tags: php

> ```
> php -v
> PHP 7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>     with Zend OPcache v7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
> ```

I use `5.6` with magento so I get errors. How can i change this? It must be 5.6?

i did this but did not work

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

Comment: check this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

You can set alias in your bash profile.

For Ubuntu edit: ~/.profile

For Centos edit: ~/.bash_profile

You can add alias before the export path command like

```
alias php='/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/bin/php'
```

After saving execute by typing `'. ~/.profile' (or '. ~/.bash_profile')` and your version is now set until you close your terminal.